# btrfs subvolume strategy on single drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, btrfs

I just installed Ubuntu 21.04 on a single SSD drive (this is my first time), with a single BTRFS-formatted partition beyond EFI. In the past running Windows, I would typically partition my drive with a system partition where the OS and programs would go, and then a data partition where my data would go. This way, OS reinstallation wouldn't affect my data, and I can have different backup strategies for the two.

As I understand it, Linux users using ext4 often do the same thing, putting /home on a separate partition. However, I think btrfs offers a better way of doing this, using subvolumes. If I have subvolumes, then I don't need to worry about resizing partitions -- they all share the full space of the single drive.

When I installed Ubuntu and selected btrfs formatting, it created the "@" and "@/home" subvolumes for me, mounted at / and /home.

This leads to my questions:

Is it really true that, if I reinstall the OS, whatever is in "@/home" won't get erased?

Where (and how) should I create additional subvolumes that are also
protected in this way from reinstallation? For example, say I want to create a subvolume called "sdata" (which will have its own folder structure). Where/how to create it, to keep it safe?

- If I do `sudo btrfs subvolume create sdata` it will create a
  subfolder in "@/home/username/sdata"
- If I do `sudo btrfs subvolume create /mnt/@sdata` it will create a
  subfolder in mnt/@sdata.
- If I do `sudo btrfs subvolume create /sdata` it will create a
  subfolder in ??

I guess my questions relate to "best" practices with btrfs on a single drive system. I like the idea of isolating my data from the OS, and having different backup/snapshot strategies for both of them, and maybe even for different subsets of my data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you want to have the subvolume created in the same location as root and home:

1. Temporarily mount the drive to some new folder

   ```
   sudo mkdir /my_disk
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /my_disk  # sda1 will need to be your partition name
   sudo ls -la /my_disk
   # you should see your subvolumes now
   ```
2. Now you can create the new subvolume inside the mounted disk

   ```
   sudo btrfs subvolume create /my_disk/sdata
   sudo ls -la /my_disk
   # you should see sdata here now
   ```
3. Mounting sdata when you boot requires you edit the /etc/fstab file

   ```
   blkid    # use this to get the needed UUID for your disk
   sudo nano /etc/fstab
   ```
4. Add the necessary info about your disk, mount point, and tags. Below is an example of you mounting sdata to the root directory, and I've included the options I use for mounting btrfs.

   ```
   # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
   #
   # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
   # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
   # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
   #
   # <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>

   UUID=????  /sdata  btrfs  defaults,subvol=sdata,ssd,noatime,space_cache,commit=120,compress=zstd  0  0
   ```

I got the mounting options from [Willi Mutschler's btrfs + luks installation guides](https://mutschler.eu/linux/install-guides/ubuntu-btrfs/#step-3-optional-optimize-mount-options-for-ssd-or-nvme-drives) which has a number of different OS installation step-by-steps. One recommendation in these guides is to rename the root subvolume to '@' so that the app [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) works correctly.

All that being said, my answer doesn't cover the process of reinstalling the same or new OS and how that is handled with btrfs subvolumes. I'm not certain of that myself. Either way I hope this helps.